# if variable = value then tick checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox

```
    <li>
        Assign Task to Every User? &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <input type="checkbox" name="display_insert_email" onchange="this.form['email'].hidden=this.checked" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="email" style="width: 400px;" value="<?php if ($task_member_id > 0){ echo $task_member_email; } else 'Please enter email address of user'?>" onclick="if(this.value=='Please enter email address of user'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Please enter email address of user'}" >
    </li>
```

These are the two areas in question, if the value of the `$project_member_id = 0` I would like the check box to be checked..

I have searched and searched but I cant find anything on this that is relevent to me, I may be searching the wrong things, but Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if($var == '0'){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
```

Comment: Input is a self closing tag :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien but i posted it in 30seconds :D , almost before the user posted the question, i'm superman

Comment: Also in this case it will be better to echo checked rather than opening and closing php tags multiple times

Comment: Not the downvoter but it's not a race, just give good answers and complete answers :)

Comment: lol i'm not racing i'm running out, the problem is i took -1 WITHOUT ANY REASON , (as usual) LOL

Comment: Check my rep, today someone is downvoting my answers without any reason, tough luck ;)

Comment: @user2286553 do you downvoted my answer? cause i really think you will get no better one :))

Comment: @Mr.Alien yep damn, sometimes i'm afraid, wtf, too many times i got downvotes randomly :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply `echo checked` if the condition is true

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($val == '1') {echo 'checked';} ?> />
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="checkbox" <?php if($variable == 1){ echo "checked"; } ?> >`

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($project_member_id == 0) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >`